# Create text file with the same row structure as the spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to convert a range of rows to a text file with the same structure as the original file. I have the following code, but the result is a text file in a single block, no row separation:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Processing')
      .addItem('Generate text file', 'menuItem1')
      .addToUi();
}

function menuItem1() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var page = ss.getSheetByName('Mipage');
  var range = page.getRange('U1:U209').getValues();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('19o17dxxlDjyiV-4wotWgVJk-b5sGmkyn');
  folder.createFile('Myfile.txt', range);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function myFunkShun() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Mipage');
  var txt=ss.getRange('U1:U209').getValues().map(function(r){return r[0];}).join('\n');
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('19o17dxxlDjyiV-4wotWgVJk-b5sGmkyn');
  folder.createFile('Myfile.txt',txt );
}
```